# remove() method is too slow

Tags: java, list, dictionary

i have a problem reading a memory trace. I've read it and saved the pages and their references on a map

Map structure:

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And then i read the file again and remove the references from the Integer List

```
FileReader arq = new FileReader(new File(Path));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(arq, 41943040);
while ( (std = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
        requestedPage = Integer.parseInt(std, 16);
        //do something
        M.map.get(requestedPage).remove(0));
    }
```

The problem is it takes too long to remove those references and for big traces it takes hours to remove the references. Does anyone have another solution?

Thank you!

Comment: What implementation of `List` are you using?

Comment: Sorry, its an ArrayList implementation

Comment: Thank you, i reverted the LinkedList and removed from the end, now it only takes 4 seconds to read the trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if `remove(0)` is the only remove operation you're going to make on this list a LinkedList is a much better data structure:

try:

```
Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Sorry, id DID change the time. From 17 minutes to 10 minutes on my trace. Unfortunately i need it to be way faster. But thank you for the tip! ;)

Comment: @FelipeCarminati 10min to remove the head of the LinkedList? I'm pretty sure the slowness is not in that method. How many elements are in the list?

Comment: I'm reading BIG files, as soon as i read a page reference from the file i go to the list of references of that page in the map and remove the first element. For the trace i'm testing, i'm removing the first element 7,7 million times. (sorry about my english).

Comment: @FelipeCarminati - removing the first element of a linked list 7.7 million times is only going to take a fraction of a second ... irrespective of the length of the list.  This is NOT where the bottleneck in your code is.  I would advise you to be scientific about this.  Profile your code.

Comment: @FelipeCarminati Don't you think that the fact that you're doing lots of IO is the cause for the slowdown and not the performance of the data structure? Removing the head of the LinkedList is very fast.

Comment: The problem wasn't just removing all the first positions of the list, i had to READ the page number, then checking if it was on the memory or not already and then REMOVE it's reference from the map. Removing the first positions (even on the LinkedList) was taking long (honestly i dont know why), but then reversing the List order and removing from the end just solved my problem. Its taking a couple of seconds.

Comment: @FelipeCarminati Removing the first element of a linked list was not 'taking long'. I suggest you weren't running the code you thought you were running, or you were misinterpreting your observations.

Comment: edit: Reverting and removing from the end DIDN'T changed the results, I made a mistake. Just using a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList solved my problems.

Comment: @FelipeCarminati make sure you mark the answer that helped you most as "Accepted" by using the tick next to it. That way people faced with the same issue will quickly see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is extremely large, the problem may be that all elements from indexes 1 through size - 1 all have to be moved: logically, the item at index n is moved to index n-1.  You can see that there's a System.arrayCopy call to do this if you look at [the `ArrayList` source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html).  The amount of time you're reporting the operations to take makes it sounds like there is a deeper problem, but you could try using a `LinkedList` or re-working your algorithm so you remove elements from the end of the list rather than the front.  With a `LinkedList`, the head element is removed, and none of the other nodes need to be modified.  If you stick with `ArrayList` but remove the last element each time instead of the first, there is no arrayCopy needed.

Also, take a look at [Guava's `Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  It's logically a `Map` with a `Collection` for the values, like you have here, but it's a much nicer interface.  There are tons of other amazing classes in the Guava libraries that you should also check out if you're not using them yet!

Comment: Using a LinkedList didn't make any difference(as it should), i will try to reverse the List order and then remove from the end as you said. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, id DID change the time. From 17 minutes to 10 minutes on my trace. Unfortunately i need it to be way faster.

Comment: Accessing files is going to be much slower than removing a node from a `LinkedList` or removing the last element from an `ArrayList`.  Are you sure that the slowness you're seeing is definitely due to the list removal and not the file accesses?

Also, try experimenting with the size of the buffer in your `BufferedReader` or not specifying a size at all and using the default size.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to put -1 instead of removing and it and it was very fast, but then again i need to test if its == -1 everytime i access the map.

Comment: Feel free to accept and up-vote the answer that suggested reversing the list and removing from the end (hint, hint).  But if you take a look at [line 169 in the source code for `LinkedList`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html), you can see that removing the first element in a `LinkedList` should be very fast, so I feel like something else was going on.  Maybe some GC overhead from nodes in the LinkedList being created and deleted so quickly?

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573970/howto-print-java-class-garbage-collection-events to see if it was indeed GC accounting for a significant amount of that slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i reverted the LinkedList and removed from the end, now it only takes 4 seconds to read the trace.

edit: Reverting and removing from the end DIDN'T changed the results, I made a mistake. Just using a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList solved my problems.