# Huge LinkedList is causing GC overhead limit, is there another solution?

Tags: java, memory, linked-list, hashmap

here is my code:

```
 public void mapTrace(String Path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileReader arq = new FileReader(new File(Path));
    BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(arq, 41943040);
    Integer page;
    String std;
    Integer position = 0;

    while ((std = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
        position++;
        page = Integer.parseInt(std, 16);
        LinkedList<Integer> values = map.get(page);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new LinkedList<>();
            map.put(page, values);
        }
        values.add(position);
    }

    for (LinkedList<Integer> referenceList : map.values()) { 
        Collections.reverse(referenceList); 
    }

}
```

This is the HashMap structure

```
       Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

For 50mb - 100mb trace files i don't have any problem, but for bigger files i have:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I don't know if the reverse method is increasing the memory use, if the LinkedList is using more space than other List structure or if the way i'm adding the list to the map is taking more space than it should. Does anyone can tell me what's using so much space?

Comment: Sounds like you probably need to run a 64-bit JVM, have ++4-8GB or more of RAM, and run Java with some strategic "-X**" switches.  For example: `-Xms2G -Xmx14G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Comment: I tried using -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
but i didn't notice any difference. (I have 64bit machine with 8gb ram)

Comment: the second parameter you pass to the BufferedReader is absurdly large.  i seriously doubt you need to buffer that much of the file in memory at one time.  the default value is probably fine, or probably something in the range of 8k - 1MB.

Comment: as for your larger question, it's hard to give better advice without knowing _what_ specifically you are doing with this data.

Comment: Does switching to an ArrayList suffer the same observed behavior? It will result in less objects overall (there are no cons-cells) and has the same *amortized* performance for adding .. the reverse for a linked list using that approach is likely *expensive*.

Comment: Well, actually, I guess *I don't know enough* about the implementation of Collections.reverse, but if it is done naively it will be "expensive".

Comment: I didn't put that parameter over there. I don't remember why it is over there, Netbeans put it over there for some reason.
I'll try to lower that value

Comment: Btw i'm reading traces of 1,5gb, I estimate like 100millions different references..

Comment: @pst The reason i changed from ArrayList to LinkedList is that i have to remove the first position everytime i read the file, and removing the first position out of an ArrayList would be way more expensive since it uses an ArrayCopy to fix the indices.

Comment: @FelipeCarminati why do you remove the first element?

Comment: You can see from line 430 in [the source for `Collections`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html), reversing a `LinkedList` should not lead to memory problems.  There are two iterators walking across the list setting the values at nodes they're iterating over.  Line 424 in that same file shows that the algorithm is also not expensive memory-wise for small lists or random access lists like `ArrayList`.  The implementors of Java were smart enough to not write a naive algorithm, @pst :-)

Comment: I think the naive part here is reversing the lists... that must be expensive. Why not just iterate them backwards?

Comment: @veer: the OP should have linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134717/remove-method-is-too-slow, where he claimed that reversing the `LinkedList` and removing from the tail is significantly faster than removing the head of a `LinkedList` or removing from the end of an `ArrayList`.  Sounds like there's something crazy going on if either of those is true.

Comment: Michael, i did more tests and forgot to update that old thread. There was a misunderstood. I just tested NOT revert the list and remove from the beggining and it showed the same results. I don't know in which part it made me confused about the results. Either way i hade the same memory problems.

Comment: Yep, @jtahlborn just found the problem. Netbeans put that value over there when i used the try-catch tip. I just changed that value to 1000 and it stopped with errors using a 200mb trace. Although i still have problems using the trace with 1.5GB. I'll run more tests with different buff sizes, does anyone have a tip about how much i should put over there? tyvm

Comment: Use a buffer size that strikes a fair balance between speed and memory usage. Since you're using large files, I suggest using a larger buffer size, but not too big.

Comment: 1MB is reasonable. I wouldn't put any more than that unless you test and determine that a larger buffer measurably improves performance. (See jtahlborn's comment above.)

Comment: I've found 256 K to be reasonable on my system. Like @NateC-K says, 1 MB is really the upper limit to what's reasonable -- any more than that, and the speed can _decrease_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone can tell me what's using so much space?

The short answer is that it is probably the space overheads of the data structure you have chosen that is using the space.

1. By my reckoning, a `LinkedList<Integer>` on a 64 bit JVM uses about 48 bytes of storage per integer in the list including the integers themselves.
2. By my reckoning, a `Map<?, ?>` on a 64 bit machine will use in the region of 48 bytes of storage per entry *excluding* the space need to represent the key and the value objects.

Now, your trace size estimates are rather too vague for me to plug the numbers in, but I'd expect a 1.5Gb trace file to need a LOT more than 2Gb of heap.

---

Given the numbers you've provided, a reasonable rule-of-thumb is that a trace file will occupy roughly 10 times its file size in heap memory ... using the data structure that you are currently using.

You don't want to configure a JVM to try to use more memory than the physical RAM available.  Otherwise, you are liable to push the machine into thrashing ... and the operating system is liable to start killing processes.  So for an 8Gb machine, I wouldn't advise going over -Xmx8g.

Putting that together, with an 8Gb machine you should be able to cope with a 600Mb trace file (assuming my estimates are correct), but a 1.5Gb trace file is not feasible.  If you really need to handle trace files that big, my advice would be to either:

- design and implement custom collection types for your specific use-case that use memory more efficiently,
- rethink your algorithms so that you don't need to hold the entire trace files in memory, or
- get a bigger machine.

---

> I did some tests before reading your comment, i put -Xmx14g and processed the 600mb file, it took some minutes(about 10) but it did fine.

The `-Xmx14g` option sets the maximum heap size.  Based on the observed behaviour, I expect that the JVM didn't need anywhere like that much memory ... and didn't request it from the OS.  And if you'd looked at memory usage in the task manager, I expect you'd have seen numbers consistent with that.

> Then i put -Xmx18g and tried to process the 1,5gb file, and its been running for about 20 minutes. My memory in the task manager is going from 7,80 to 7,90. I wonder if this will finish, how could i use MORE memory than i have? Does it use the HD as virtual memory?

Yes that it is what it does.

Yes, each page of your processes virtual address space corresponds to a page on the hard disc.

If you've got more virtual pages than physical memory pages, at any given time some of those virtual memory pages will live on disk only.  When your application tries to use a one of those non-resident pages, the VM hardware generates an interrupt, and the operating system finds an unused page and populates it from the disc copy and then hands control back to your program.  But if your application is busy, then it will have had to *make* that physical memory page by evicting another page.  And that may have involved writing the contents of the evicted page to disc.

The net result is that when you try to use significantly more virtual address pages than you have physical memory, the application generates lots of interrupts that result in lots of disc reads and writes.  This is known as thrashing.  If your system thrashes too badly, the system will spend most of its waiting for disc reads and writes to finish, and performance will drop dramatically.  And on some operating systems, the OS will attempt to "fix" the problem by killing processes.

Comment: Exactly. As I said on the question i was gettin the "GC overhead limit exceeded" even using a 200mb trace. Now i can use this trace without problems, but using a 600mb and the 1,5gb trace is giving "Java heap space" problem.

Comment: Each reference from file is an hexa value, here you can see which traces i'm using if you want: 

http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~sfkaplan/research/trace-reduction/index.html

(Download them from the 'Original reference traces' section)

espresso = 1,52 GB / grobner = 37mb / gnuplot = 208 MB / lindsay = 600mb

@Stephen C, each Hexa reference is converted to Integer and put in the map as the KEY. And a position from that reference is put in the  list. I'm not sure if i'm clear enough :/

Comment: @FelipeCarminati - what is **still** not clear is the actual data volumes; i.e. the number of unique keys and the average number of entries in each list.  These are the numbers from which it will be possible to estimate how much heap space you actually need.  Is THAT clear?

Comment: (And no I don't intend to do a whole bunch of background reading on your trace files to figure it out for you.  It is your problem.  You do the research, and plug the numbers into the equations I've provided.)

Comment: Thank you for you equations, i did use then I was not sure enough about my conclusions. I put the references there so maybe you would like to see how they are. As i said, hexa numbers were converted to Integer to be saved on the map. This 1,52gb trace has 77 different pages and 326938362 total references. That means it uses (326938362x48bytes) = ~15gb of space. (Is that right?)
The 600mb file use ~6gb of space. If i put -Xmx14g , that would make possible to read the 600mb file, is that right? (if my calc is correct).
What is the maximum -Xmx i could use? (My memory is 8gb)

Comment: I did some tests before reading your comment, i put -Xmx14g and processed the 600mb file, it took some minutes(about 10) but it did fine. Then i put -Xmx18g and tried to process the 1,5gb file, and its been running for about 20 minutes. My memory in the task manager is going from 7,80 to 7,90. I wonder if this will finish, how could i use MORE memory than i have? Does it use the HD as virtual memory?

Answer (score 0):

Further to Stephen's quite reasonable answer, everything has its limit and your code simply isn't [scalable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability).

In case where the input is "large" (as in your case), the only reasonable approach is a stream based approach, which while (usually) more complicated to write, uses very little memory/resources. Essentially you hold in memory only what you need to process the *current* task then release it asap.

You may find that unix command line tools are your best weapon, perhaps using a combination of `awk`, `sed`, `grep` etc to massage your raw data into hopefully a usable "end format".

I once stopped a colleague from writing a java program to read in and parse XML and issue insert statements to a database: I showed him how to use a series of piped commands to produce executable SQL which was then piped directly into the database command line tool. Took about 30 minutes to get it right, but job done. And the file was massive , so in java it would have required a SAC parser and JDBC, which aren't fun.

Comment: ty for your efforts to help me! :)

I'm actually doing an article for OS subject which is test the different Page Substitution Algorythms efficiency; LRU , LFU compared to this one (OPTIMUM). It may have other solutions to my problem like using files to save info, but i believe this solution would be the best one to exemplify and explain.

Answer (score 0):

to build this structure, I would put those data in a key/value datastore like [berkeleydb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html) for java.

peusdo-code

```
putData(db,page,value)
 {
 Entry key=new Entry();
 Entry data=new Entry();
 List<Integer> L=new LinkedList<Integer>();;
 IntegerBinding.intToEntry(page,key);
 if(db.get(key,data)==OperationStatus.SUCCESS)
    {
    TupleInput t=new TupleInput(data);
    int n=t.readInt();

    for(i=0;i< n;++n) L.add(n);
    }

  L.add(value);
  TupleOutput out=new TupleOutput();
  out.writeInt(L.size());

  for(int v: L)  out.writeInt(v);
  data=new Entry(out.toByteArray());
  db.put(key,data);
 }
```