# JVM memory with xmpp to GCM server

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I have developped a server side for GCM that accepts upstream from Android-->GCM-->my server based on this [Project](https://github.com/writtmeyer/gcm_server/tree/master/src/com/grokkingandroid/sampleapp/samples/gcm/ccs/server) and sends messages from my server tog com to android.
(I uses Smack341.jar, and send and receive without using "chat" Object I send directly to GCM by custom functions that create JSON Messages from My Map<>)
I have modified many things:
1. my messages is not plane text but MAP that contain 15 fields.
2. No direct Connection  to xmpp, all the communications are done via GCM server.
3.my Server get the target regID (one of my message fields) and send the message to that RegId.
4.I have added Filter class that read field called(M_type=message type) contains my own types (not xmpp types) ie online status type typing type, stoptyping type getFriendsList type ect... the server behave according to these types:

```
  switch (  msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TYPECLM)) {
   case  Constants.GETFRIENDS: //get friends list...
     filter.Sendfriebdlist(msg.getPayload(),ccsClient);
     break;

    case Constants.ADDFRIEND:
           String Toregid=msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM);
           filter.HandleFriendReq(msg.getPayload(),msg,ccsClient,Toregid);
           break;

 case Constants.ADDFRIENDRESPOND:
   filter.HandleAddFriendResond(msg, ccsClient, msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)); 
   break;        
 case "ACKBACK":
           filter.HandleAckfromU2U(ccsClient, msg.getPayload(),filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)));
           break;

        case "text":
           filter.HandleMsg(msg.getPayload(),msg,ccsClient,filter.key2reg(TorDevice));
           SendAckBack(msg.getFrom(),ccsClient,msg.getPayload().get(Constants.MESSAGE_ID_CLM));
           break;

        case "IMAGE":
           msg.getPayload().put(Constants.TO_CLM,filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)));
           String url = msg.getPayload().get(Constants.URLCLM);
           url ="http:/"+"/"+ url;
           url=url.replace("\\","/");
           System.out.println("image url = " +url);
          msg.getPayload().put(Constants.URLCLM,url);
           SendAckBack(msg.getFrom(),ccsClient,msg.getPayload().get(Constants.MESSAGE_ID_CLM));
           filter.HandleMsg(msg.getPayload(),msg,ccsClient,filter.key2reg(TorDevice)); 
           break;

   case "PROFILE":
    msg.getPayload().put(Constants.TO_CLM,filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)));
        String urlP = msg.getPayload().get(Constants.URLCLM);
          urlP ="http:/"+"/"+urlP;
           urlP=urlP.replace("\\","/");
   System.out.println(" URLCLM= "+msg.getPayload().get(Constants.URLCLM));      
msg.getPayload().put(Constants.URLCLM,urlP);         
 filter.updatePhoto( msg.getPayload(),ccsClient,msg);
   break;

   case "VIDEO":
           msg.getPayload().put(Constants.TO_CLM,filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)));
           String url2 = msg.getPayload().get(Constants.URLCLM);

            url2 ="http:/"+"/"+ url2;
           url2=url2.replace("\\","/");
           System.out.println("video url = " +url2);
           msg.getPayload().put(Constants.URLCLM,url2);
           SendAckBack(msg.getFrom(),ccsClient,msg.getPayload().get(Constants.MESSAGE_ID_CLM));
            filter.HandleMsg(msg.getPayload(),msg,ccsClient,filter.key2reg(TorDevice));
           break;

   case "AUDIO":
            msg.getPayload().put(Constants.TO_CLM,filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)));
           String url3 = msg.getPayload().get(Constants.URLCLM);
             url3 ="http:/"+"/"+ url3;
           url3=url3.replace("\\","/");
         msg.getPayload().put(Constants.URLCLM,url3);
           SendAckBack(msg.getFrom(),ccsClient,msg.getPayload().get(Constants.MESSAGE_ID_CLM));
            filter.HandleMsg(msg.getPayload(),msg,ccsClient,filter.key2reg(TorDevice));
        break;

   case "BLOCK":
       filter.block(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.FROMCLM),msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM),ccsClient);
           break;

   case "UNBLOCK":
       filter.unblock(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.FROMCLM),msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM),ccsClient);
           break;   

   case "REMOVE":
       filter.removef(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.FROMCLM),msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM),ccsClient);
           break;

   case "typing":
       System.err.println("Typing");
       //filter.sendtyping(msg.getPayload().get(filter.key2reg(Constants.TO_CLM)),filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)),ccsClient,msg.getPayload());
           break;    
        case "stoptyping":
      // filter.sendStoptyping(filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)),filter.key2reg(msg.getPayload().get(Constants.TO_CLM)),ccsClient,msg.getPayload());
           System.err.println("Stop Typing");
            break;
```

**Problem: 1** I consider that xmpp server have one user (GCM) and he "didn't know that I have hundreds!!

but when the users begin interact (chat via their android devices)  and the number of uploaded messages increased I got Out of memory error...

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

OR

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

sometimes:

```
Exception in thread "Smack Packet reader(0)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Java heap space
```

my server device have 4GB physic RAM. and I run my server on 3gb as max memory size:

```
java  -Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -jar newsrvrSodfa.jar
```

I don't know why I got that out of memory error. may data type is just MAP

**Problem: 2** the xmpp spends about 10-20 seconds in ( interceptPacket ) !!

I hope I succeed in describing my problem. ask me if anything not clear.

**update** 1.the server itself is on Windows server 2008 R2 standard
2. the Error output:

```
 at javax.swing.text.GapContent.getChars(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.getText(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getText(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakSpot(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getMinimumSpan(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI$PlainParagraph.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JTextArea.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: See if this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151580/huge-linkedlist-is-causing-gc-overhead-limit-is-there-another-solution/12151934#12151934)

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion that your Map is causing the OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: First thank for the person who vote down! with no reason!

@Flow I need these Maps.. can you explain your idea?
- larryp thanks I will read it now.