# Solr becoming unavailable while adding documents

Tags: node.js, solr

We have a Solr 4.51 (Debian) installation that is being filled up by a node.js app. Both reside on the same machine. We are adding about 250 to 350 documents per second. Solr is configured with auto-commit (1000 ms soft / 15000 ms hard).

After round about 100 to 150 seconds Solr becomes unavailable for one up to five seconds. So `http.request()` returns `EADDRNOTAVAIL`. In the meantime we have a workaround, which retries to add the document every 500 ms. So after one up to 10 tries Solr becomes available again and everything works fine (up to the next break).

We are wondering if this is *normal*. Or could the described behaviour be due to any misconfiguration?

There is **no** error or warning entry in the Solr log file. Notably while being unavailable the cpu workload of the corresponding Solr java process falls from 30 % down to almost zero.

Of course our node.js app always waits on the answer of the `http.request`, so there should not be any parallel requests that could rise any overflow.

What could be the reason that Solr makes these "coffee breaks"?

Thanks for any hint!

**EDIT:**

When looking into the Solr log (haviing auto-commit enabled) while the error occurs. The log file sais:

```
80583779 [commitScheduler-9-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler â start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=true,prepareCommit=false}
80583788 [commitScheduler-9-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher â Opening Searcher@1263c036 main
80583789 [commitScheduler-9-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler â end_commit_flush
80583789 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore â QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@1263c036 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1lv:67657:nrt _opz(4.5.1):C1371694/84779:delGen=1 _p29(4.5.1):C52149/1067:delGen=1 _q0p(4.5.1):C48456 _q0z(4.5.1):C2434 _q19(4.5.1):C2583 _q1j(4.5.1):C3195 _q1t(4.5.1):C2633 _q23(4.5.1):C3319 _q1c(4.5.1):C351 _q2n(4.5.1):C3277 _q2x(4.5.1):C2618 _q2d(4.5.1):C2621 _q2w(4.5.1):C201)}
80583789 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore â QuerySenderListener done.
80583789 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore â [base] Registered new searcher Searcher@1263c036 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1lv:67657:nrt _opz(4.5.1):C1371694/84779:delGen=1 _p29(4.5.1):C52149/1067:delGen=1 _q0p(4.5.1):C48456 _q0z(4.5.1):C2434 _q19(4.5.1):C2583 _q1j(4.5.1):C3195 _q1t(4.5.1):C2633 _q23(4.5.1):C3319 _q1c(4.5.1):C351 _q2n(4.5.1):C3277 _q2x(4.5.1):C2618 _q2d(4.5.1):C2621 _q2w(4.5.1):C201)}
80593917 [commitScheduler-6-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler â start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=false,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
80593931 [commitScheduler-6-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore â SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits: num=2
```

So at first glance it looks like Solr refuses the http connections while performing a soft commit. **BUT**,

- there have been many soft commits before without refusals
- there will be many soft commit afterwards without refusalss
- and (most important) when disabling auto-commit at all the http requests from node are refused anyway (more or less at the same stage as if aut-commit wre enabled).

The Solr log file with auto-commit disabled just stops here (while adding the documents):

```
153314 [qtp1112461277-10] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d009155]} 0 0
153317 [qtp1112461277-16] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d009156]} 0 0
153320 [qtp1112461277-17] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d009157]} 0 1
153322 [qtp1112461277-18] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d009158]} 0 0
153325 [qtp1112461277-13] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d009159]} 0 0
153329 [qtp1112461277-19] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d00915a]} 0 1
153331 [qtp1112461277-12] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d00915b]} 0 0
153334 [qtp1112461277-15] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d00915c]} 0 0
153336 [qtp1112461277-11] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor â [base] webapp=/solr path=/update/json params={commit=false&wt=json} {add=[52c14621fc45c82d4d00915d]} 0 0
```

So here is no hint anymore that commiting or indexing could be the reason that Solr refuses any (any!) http request for 1-3 seconds.

**EDIT2:**

It is also remarkable, that if we switch root-logging to `ALL`, Solr becomes slower (that is obvious due to the more verbose logging) but also the error vanishes. So there are no refusal periods any more. This looks like it is also a timing problem...

**EDIT3:**

In the meantime I found out, that the unavailability of Solr only affects my node application. While not beeing available for node.js I can make requests from the Solr Web Admin. I also tried to connect from node.js to a different webserver whle not beeing able to access Solr. That works! So this is weird, my node.js app cannot access Solr for some seconds, but any other app can. Any idea what could be the reason for that?

Comment: might be GC related. Have you logged GC details already?

Comment: Try increasing the values for auto-commit duration (I would raise them both ten folds).

Comment: @Persimmonium: I have used --trace-gc. There is nothing noticable. To my mind GC could yet not be the reason for the errors, because a GC would pause the node process, not Solr or the http connection, wouldn't? Node is working all the time...

Comment: @mjalajel: I have changed the two auto-commit (soft/hard) times by the factor 10. No change! I have then deactivated autoCommit  in solrconfig.xml completely. No change! This does not seem to be the reason.

Comment: @Persimmonium: Or do you mean the GC of Java (and not node.js)? How would I trace that? This did not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573970/howto-print-java-class-garbage-collection-events

Comment: @heinob Yes, I meant java GC. Look at this page for instance http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/ for details

Comment: @Persimmonium: No, GC is not the reason. There are no special GC infos during the time of unavailabilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. It is a problem of the default global http agent. See full description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991551/eaddrnotavail-after-many-http-get-requests-to-localhost/20993398#20993398).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a full indexing , its a bad idea to use auto-commit .

The thing happening is at every hard commit a new  index file is formed . and your policy shows that at every 15000 docs a commit happens . which may create a optimization cycle every 50 seconds (300 docs /sec ) and during optimization the solr server refuses to serve queries as its maximum resources are being utilized for optimization , hence if doing a "Big/Bulk/Full INdexing " comment out auto commits , it would speed up your indexing .
Try to comment out transaction logs for big indexings as these are overhead in bulk indexing scenario

regards

Rajat

Comment: O.k. I see! But if I understand you right, this also could happen in production. Because there I would switch auto-commit on. How would I then prevent "request refusals" while hard committing?

Comment: By error I forgot to mention that the hard commit is not 15000 documents but 15000 ms (now corrected!), so there should be a hard commit every 15 seconds. Does that contradict your answer now?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more data ,

1  volume of number of documents per indexing cycle .(Number of documents per minute or any thing like it )

2  what purpose you are using solr (Type of search NRT or with a Delay)

3  what is  your solr configuration (master slave etc and their purpose )

Process of a commit as I have seen is  . while indexing on a commit solr "Ques " up the indexing requests when its free it just indexes them although it may seem it has stopped , but indexing goes on.

Look in to the warm up count for caches , I am assuming that you have a master slave configuration . So on master warm up count for caches should be zero because in any way you are clearing all caches in every 15 seconds

Secondly 
I feel is it is highly unlikely for you to run into halting problem on production system .
because you will have a large index and  rest would be small files so in this scenario  merging would be of small segments but I would be in a better position to answer the question if you could answer questions which I asked

regards

Rajat

Comment: 1) While transfering data we add about 300 documents per second. With auto-soft-commit=1000ms that should be the number of documents indexed. Hard commit is 15000ms. 2) We use it within a business application. So we need the data more or less real time. That is the reason for softcommit being so short. 3) The described behaviour happens even on our development machine. So standalone, no replication. More infos...see the edit in the question.

Comment: Btw: You should pass such enquiries in a comment and not in an answer.

Comment: Hi, you can try to increase the hard commit 10 folds for delta indexing , increase your merge factor . But once in a while it would go into  optimization of smaller files . ,you can Optimize index weekly or daily as a maintenance activity so the suggestions are increase hard commit to 10 folds , increase merge factor to avoid merging of files, optimize daily or weekly as a maintenance activity for performance