# Java 11 GC timestamp

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-11

`-Xlog:gc*:/opt/myapp/gc.log`
doesn't print timestamp by default. It just has `uptimemillis`. How to add `time` to above vm option so that it can print timestamp as well.
PS: I am on Java 11 and don't have the luxury to use `-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a replacement for the garbage collection JVM args in Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144713/is-there-a-replacement-for-the-garbage-collection-jvm-args-in-java-11/54145207#54145207)

Comment: in the answer of the above question, it says reason: `Time/date stamps are logged by the framework.` which is not the case. I don't see timestamp printed by `-Xlog:gc*`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This prints date/time as well `-Xlog:gc*:/opt/myapp/gc.log:time`

Comment: I would suggest `-Xlog:gc*:/opt/myapp/gc.log:time,level,tags` to include all the default decorators.